# Highcharts.JS, Pie chart links to onpage #div ajax content links

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

The below was the solution on how to link pie / slice / data sections to URLS.. But this approach seemed to not work for me, I would like the links to link to link `#inlinedivcontentareas` any suggestions?

```
    series: [{
        point: {
        events: {
            click: function(e) {
                location.href = e.point.url;
                e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        },
        innerSize: '30%',
        data: [
            {name: 'Shop', y: 10, url: '/#pie2'},
            {name: 'Buy', y: 10,  url: '/#pie3'},
            {name: 'Own', y: 10,  url: '/#pie4'}
        ]
    }]
});
```

**I'm assuming it has something to do with this. How can I alter the below to go to #divs**

```
location.href = e.point.url;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code:

```
$('#container1').highcharts({
        series: [{
            point:{
                events:{
                    click:function(){
                        location.href=this.url;
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            },
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [{y:1,url:'#container2'},2,3]
        }]
    });

     $('#container2').highcharts({
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [1,2,3]
        }]
    });
```

For me its working properly, after click on the first point, I am moved to the object with id "container2".

Answer (score 1):

You would use [`location.hash`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp)

```
location.hash = 'target';
```

[Linking to Anchor from Chart @jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/kmq289qw/)